# Name of a "triplet" inside an eighth beat

Tags: notation, tuplet

I've recently been creating my own rendition of Amazing Grace, and while I was working to add a bit of stylistic elements to it, I imagined a melody in my head which would require 3 beats in the space of one eighth note.

I am aware that this sort of thing exists, as I have often heard it, but I have not managed to find either the name of this note, or how it is written.

To add a bit more clarity, I am looking for three equal beats in the space of one eighth beat. Here is an image of what said note might look like (at least how I imagined)

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That would be called a "sextuplet", or sometimes a "sixteenth-note triplet".  It's notated with a "3" or a "6" above a group of notes with two flags/beams.  It's a type of [tuplet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuplet)- so, a "3" with two beams indicates three notes in the space of one eigth note, and a "6" with two beams indicates 6 notes in the space of a quarter note.  See this example:

[image]

It's unclear exactly what rhythm you want, from your example notation.

Comment: Thanks so much, the first example is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: If there's 6 of them, it's a sextuplet.   If just 3, a triplet.

Comment: Hold on, not "eighth-note triplet"? Referring to the fact it's dividing an eighth note into three equal parts

Comment: I believe they're called "sixteenth note triplets" because the notation uses two beams/flags, like sixteenth notes.

Comment: Yes.  Triplets come in any note length.  All that matters is that three of them fill the time normally taken by two.  They're always 'triplets'.